# Form Submit Message in React

Tags: reactjs, popup, submit, alert, form-submit

I am trying to have a message appear with "You are now subscribed to {SUBSCRIPTION}." when a user submits a form in React. I am very new to React, so I feel like I am missing something small (hopefully).

So far, I have something that looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                newsletter: props.newsletter
            }
        }
    }

    handleNewsletterInput(event) {
        var user = this.state.user;

        user.newsletter = event.target.value;

        // Update the state object
        this.setState({ user: user })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        var user = this.state.user;

        user.newsletter = event.target.value;

        alert("You are now subscribed to " + { user } + ".")
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Subscribe</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <label>
                        <p>Newsletter Type:</p>
                        <input
                            id='newsletter'
                            type='text'
                            name='newsletter'
                            value={this.state.user.newsletter}
                            onChange={this.handleNewsletterInput.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button
                        type='submit'
                        id='subscribe'
                        name='subscribe'>
                        Subscribe
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );

     ...
```

When I run it, I get a message saying "You are now subscribed to [object Object]." What am I doing wrong, and how can I get [object Object] to say the name of the newsletter?

Comment: The message you are getting is correct. this.state.user is indeed an object. It should be this.state.user.newsletter if you are trying to show the name of newsletter

Comment: @RabeehMohammed Unfortunately, I receive an error when I do that. This is why I am confused lol ```./src/components/SubscribeForm.js
SyntaxError: SubscribeForm.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (30:51)

  28 |         user.newsletter = event.target.value;
  29 |
> 30 |         alert("You are now subscribed to " + { user.newsletter } + ".")
     |                                                    ^
  31 |     }
  32 |
  33 |     render() { ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a React issue.

```
alert("You are now subscribed to " + { user } + ".")
```

Here you are concatenating an object with a string. The object is coerced into "[object Object]" string because any object v.toString() gives this by default(unless explicitly set), as its a memory reference. Try this line instead:

```
alert("You are now subscribed to " + JSON.stringify(user) + ".")
```

> and how can I get [object Object] to say the name of the newsletter?

```
alert("You are now subscribed to " + user.newsletter + ".")
```

> Unfortunately, I receive an error when I do that. `alert("You are now subscribed to " + { user.newsletter } + ".")`

This syntax you have mentioned in the comment below question is wrong. `{user.newsletter}` is not correct syntax, it is neither an object nor a string.

Edit after `handleNewsletterInput` added:

```
handleNewsletterInput(event) {
        var user = this.state.user;

        user.newsletter = event.target.value;

        // Update the state object
        this.setState({ user: user })
}
```

The above will not update state because you have not changed the memory reference of `user` variable. React will not know that the state has changed as it will do comparison `prevState===currentState` and it will give `true`, as its in the same memory location. Try this instead:

```
handleNewsletterInput(event) {
        const { user } = this.state;

        const updatedUser = {
            ...user,
            newsletter: event.target.value
        }

        // Update the state object
        this.setState({ user: updatedUser })
}
```

Edit 2:
You've also made a mistake here -

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        var user = this.state.user;

        user.newsletter = event.target.value;

        alert("You are now subscribed to " + { user } + ".")
}
```

This event is the submit event, you do not need the first two lines here.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        // Do something like send form data to backend here.

        alert("You are now subscribed to " + this.state.user.newsletter + ".")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it is still not quite right. Here is what the alert says "You are now subscribed to {}." What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You'd have to put the function handleNewsletterInput in the code example as it runs onChange. Without seeing what is written there I cannot advise, because it seems that function is not updating state correctly.

Comment: like this? `alert("You are now subscribed to " + JSON.stringify(this.handleNewsletterInput(event)) + ".")` I now get "You are now subscribed to undefined." Thank you for your help so far btw! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I added the function to the original post above too for your reference! @indiansage

Comment: Updated answer @325

Comment: Why are you doing `JSON.stringify(this.handleARNInput(event))`? This function will be called, and it does not have any output to stringify. I am assuming you have renamed handleNewsletterInput as handleARNInput. Do this: `alert("You are now subscribed to " + user.newsletter + ".")`

Comment: I thought I had to do that since you previously mentioned it. This is what I have now: ```handleNewsletterInput(event) {
        const { user } = this.state;

        const updatedUser = {
            ...user,
            newsletter: event.target.value
        }

        // Update the state object
        this.setState({ user: updatedUser })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        var user = this.state.user;

        user.newsletter = event.target.value;

        alert("You are now subscribed to " + user.newsletter + ".")
    } ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234376/discussion-between-indiansage-and-325).